# Как сделать маску ввода банковской карты с звездочками?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно такое реализовать с помощью masked input?

Comment: input type password попробуйте

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

Comment: Это же не пароль

Answer (score 3):

Если используете плагин maskedinput, то можно его настроить так:

```
    //задаете x как любое число 
    $.mask.definitions['x']='[0-9]';

    //устанавливаете саму маску и * вместо подчеркивания
    $("id").mask("4276-xxxx-xx98-7654", {placeholder: '*'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, маска должна показать ошибку только при неверной следующей цифре.

Нам придется создать длиннющее выражение:

- где текущий символ должен совпадать
- а последующего может пока не быть

Это позитивный просмотр вперед `^(?=(1(?=(2$)|$))|$)`:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=` - за которой может быть что-то
- `|$` - или может ничего не быть

```js
const mask = '4276-xxxx-xx98-7654'

function createRegExp(mask) {
  // Собирать будем с последнего символа.
  const array = Array.from(mask).reverse()
  // Окружаем началом и концом
  const result = (src) => `^(?=(${src})|$)`
  // Замена
  const char = (v) => /\d|-/.test(v) ? `${v}` : `\\d`
  // Последний символ устанавливается несколько иначе - после него всегда конец строки
  const end = `${char(array.shift())}$`
  // На случай только одного символа
  if (!array.length) {
    return result(end)
  }
  return result(array.reduce((a, v) => {
    return `${char(v)}(?=(${a})|$)`
  }, end))
}
const src = createRegExp(mask)
// Для просмотра
console.log(src)
const regExp = new RegExp(src)

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
  const value = this.value.trim()
  if (regExp.test(value)) {
    this.style.color = '#000'
  } else {
    this.style.color = 'red'
  }
})
```

```html
<div>4276-xxxx-xx98-7654</div>
<input type="text">
```

Осталось встроить проверку кол-ва символов, по которой можно активировать необходимую кнопку с сообщением - "Все верно :)"

**UPD**
А я видимо вопроса не понял, там звездочки надо.
Ну ладно, оставлю, может кому и это пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Отображение "звездочек" можно сделать используя регулярные выражения, например так:

```js
const str = '1234-5678-9012-3456'
const strRepl = str.slice(5,12).replace(/\d/g, 'x')
const strNew = str.slice(0, 5) + strRepl + str.slice(12)
console.log(strNew)
```

Или, например, совсем в лоб:

```js
const str = '1234-5678-9012-3456'
const strNew = str.slice(0, 5) + 'xxxx-xx' + str.slice(12)
console.log(strNew)
```

Проверку можно также сделать при помощи регулярных выражений

```js
const str = '1234-5678-9012-3456'
const regex = /^1|^8|^9|^0/

if (regex.test(str)) {
  console.log('Error')
} else {
  console.log('Ok')
}
```

Comment: А как это при вводе делать?

Comment: Вам необходимо "на лету" это делать? Если так то это называется контролируемый ввод и, например, в реакте реализуется так https://habr.com/ru/post/502034/ Или через хук useState.

Comment: А чистым js или плагинами никак не получится?

Comment: Ну как вариант вам предложили через плагин maskedinput. Если там нет встроенной проверки, то можно взять исходники этого плагина и добавить эту проверку.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!